# MySQL table partitioning on timestamp

Tags: mysql, sql

I have partitioned a table (because of an out of memory error - table got too big).  I have partitioned it on a timestamp column as shown below:

```
CREATE TABLE test (
    fname VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    lname VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    dob timestamp NOT NULL
)
PARTITION BY RANGE( unix_timestamp(dob) ) (
    PARTITION p2012 VALUES LESS THAN (unix_timestamp('2013-01-01 00:00:00')),
    PARTITION p2013 VALUES LESS THAN (unix_timestamp('2014-01-01 00:00:00')),
    PARTITION pNew VALUES LESS THAN MAXVALUE
);
```

I was hoping that the process of partitioning would also help in speeding up a couple of my queries whihc take a few hours to run; however, this type of partitioning doesn't seem to kick in and all partitions are still being used and scanned through for the queries.  I have tried, and failed, with a couple more approaches:

1) Tried to use different range for the partitioning

```
CREATE TABLE t2 (
    fname VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    lname VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    region_code TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    dob timestamp NOT NULL
)
PARTITION BY RANGE( YEAR(dob) ) (
    PARTITION p2012 VALUES LESS THAN (2013),
    PARTITION p2013 VALUES LESS THAN (2014),
    PARTITION pNew VALUES LESS THAN MAXVALUE
);
```

However, that results in an error: `Error Code: 1486. Constant, random or timezone-dependent expressions in (sub)partitioning function are not allowed`

2) Gave up on changing partitioning to be recognized by the query optimizer, and as suggested in MySQL's Doc - [18.5 Partition Selection](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/partitioning-selection.html) tried specifying which partitions to use in the select statement instead:

```
select * from t2 partition (p2012)
```

But, that returns a syntax error `Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(p2012) LIMIT 0, 1000' at line 1`

Does anybody have any suggestions what else I could try to utilize table partitioning to optimize the queries?

Comment: so the partition `p2012` really exist in your table?

Comment: What is the exact MySQL version you're using?

Comment: I did a little bit more testing... I tried the same test on a machine with 5.5 installed and the query optimizer does utilize partitioning as expected.  Since I'm stuck with 5.1, I'm out of luck.  I was trying to avoid this, but I think I will resort to adding an index on the dob column to speed up the queries.

Answer (score 2):

You can use UNIX_TIMESTAMP() function. Example from MySQL docs:

```
CREATE TABLE quarterly_report_status (
    report_id INT NOT NULL,
    report_status VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    report_updated TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
)
PARTITION BY RANGE ( UNIX_TIMESTAMP(report_updated) ) (
    PARTITION p0 VALUES LESS THAN ( UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2008-01-01 00:00:00')  ),
    PARTITION p1 VALUES LESS THAN ( UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2008-04-01 00:00:00') ),
    PARTITION p2 VALUES LESS THAN ( UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2008-07-01 00:00:00') ),
    PARTITION p3 VALUES LESS THAN ( UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2008-10-01 00:00:00') ),
    PARTITION p4 VALUES LESS THAN ( UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2009-01-01 00:00:00') ),
    PARTITION p5 VALUES LESS THAN ( UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2009-04-01 00:00:00') ),
    PARTITION p6 VALUES LESS THAN ( UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2009-07-01 00:00:00') ),
    PARTITION p7 VALUES LESS THAN ( UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2009-10-01 00:00:00') ),
    PARTITION p8 VALUES LESS THAN ( UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2010-01-01 00:00:00') ),
    PARTITION p9 VALUES LESS THAN (MAXVALUE)
```

);

You can find it in:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/partitioning-range.html.

Comment: If you use TIMESTAMP(N) you will need to FLOOR(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(report_updated))

Answer (score 1):

1. You can do this if you use DATE or DATETIME instead of TIMESTAMP as the data type.

   ```
   CREATE TABLE t2 (
       fname VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
       lname VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
       region_code TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
       dob DATETIME NOT NULL
   )
   PARTITION BY RANGE( YEAR(dob) ) (
       PARTITION p2012 VALUES LESS THAN (2013),
       PARTITION p2013 VALUES LESS THAN (2014),
       PARTITION pNew VALUES LESS THAN MAXVALUE
   );
   ```
2. Using the partition-selection hint is only supported in MySQL 5.6 and later.

   See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/partitioning-selection.html
   Note that the page of the manual is only for MySQL 5.6. If you try to click on MySQL 5.5 documentation link, it redirects you back to 5.6.

Answer (score -1):

The wrong is that, This field dob is not unique key!

you can use this command:

```
  CREATE TABLE t2 (
    fname VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    lname VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    region_code TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    dob timestamp NOT NULL,
    unique 'dob' (dob)
 )
```

or the table is exist:

alter table t2 add UNIQUE(dob)

You can try it!